# Pure Virtual Function Used?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, pure-virtual

I am building a game in unreal but I recently encountered a nasty bug that crashes the game.  I've dug into the engine source and traced the bug back to the following line, where the program is reading 0x0 (in BodyInstance.cpp, if you care and have the engine source):

```
 PxU32 FilterFlags0 = Shape0->getSimulationFilterData().word3 & 0xFFFFFF;
```

When I looked this up in the PhysX documentation [it says](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/apireference/files/classPxShape.html#bfa95e009f300060ba648637fb685686) that `getSimulationFilterData` is a pure virtual function.  I have also checked that Shape0 is a `PxShape*`.  It is initialized on this line:

```
const PxShape* Shape0 = Pair->shapes[0];
```

How is this pure virtual function being called from a non-derived class?  I have to be missing something, please help!

(I've already asked this on the ue4 answerhub but asking a question there is like screaming for help on a desert island.)

Comment: FWIW both the UE4 IRC and Discord groups are extremely helpful if you aren't getting anywhere with the answerhub.

Comment: But does what `Shape0` points at actually implement `getSimulationFilterData`? The error received suggests no.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Normally, the runtime type of the object pointed to by `Shape0` would have to be a derived type which defines all pure virtual methods from the base class, including `getSimulationFilterData()`.  But for example, if `*Shape0` happens to be in the process of being constructed or destructed when this code is reached, then calling that virtual method is undefined behavior.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to include that it was reading 0x0. That's very important :)  Editing now.

Comment: Can someone just confirm for me that if `Pair->shapes[0]` is a derived class of `PxShape` that implements `getSimulationFilterData` then the line that is currently throwing the error will work fine, assuming that `getSimulationFilterData` is not called while `Shape0` is being constructed.

Comment: @user393454: How do you expect anyone to "confirm" that for you? Only you know what `Pair` is in your code and what `Pair->shapes[0]` is. How is `Pair->shapes` declared? How is `Pair->shapes[i]` initialized?

Comment: What do you mean by "the program is reading 0x0"? Is `Shape0`'s value 0x0? If so you've stumbled over a null pointer, and your job is now to figure out why it is a null pointer.

Comment: @AnT It's not really my code, it's the unreal engine source code.  The debugger says that `Pair->shapes[0]` is a `PxShape*` and that `Pair->shapes` is a `PxShape*[ ]`.

Comment: @user4581301 Sorry for not being more precise, I know from the debugger that `Shape0` does not have a value of 0x0.  So it must be the pure virtual function called in that line.

Comment: @user393454 You can't call a pure virtual function at runtime because you can't construct an abstract object. This would be a compile time error, not a runtime error. If you want to find the concrete class of `PxShape`, find where it is actually constructed.